# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ']'

Tags: php, html, syntax-error

I am getting error on my site Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ']' in /home/kbccsystem/kbccsystem.php.xdomain.jp/public_html/register.php on line 69

My PHP code in FROM line 69 to 96 is:

```
$allowedformat = array("gif" , "jpeg", "jpg" , "png");
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["img_path"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);

if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
&& ($_FILES["file]["size"] < 20000 )
&& in_array($extension, $allowedformat)) {

if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES["img_path"]["tmp_name"]))
{
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["img_path"]["tmp_name"], "shop_image/" .$_FILES["img_path"]["name"]))
{ 
chmod("shop_image/" .$_FILES["img_path"]["name"], 0644);
  echo "アップロードしました。";
    }else{
      echo "ファイルをアップロードできませんでした。";
    }
    }else{
      echo "ファイルが選択されていません。";
    }
    }
    }
```

Start line is 69. Last line is line 96.

please help :)
thankyou.

Comment: Use a text editor with syntax highlighting. It will prevent stupid stuff like this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The syntax highlighter shows your error. You're missing a quote around one of your array keys:

```
&& ($_FILES["file]["size"] < 20000 )
              ^^^^^
              HERE
```

It should be:

```
   && ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000 )
```

Comment: Thankyou.
but now i am getting error
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in /home/kbccsystem/kbccsystem.php.xdomain.jp/public_html/register.php on line 85

Comment: You probably have an extra `}`. Match all of your opening brackets with a closing bracket. That's how you'll find there erroneous one.

Comment: That's another question. Please give the person that answered a vote that it was answered. This is not a help forum. But, it looks like you have an extra } around line 85. (This is why professionals use indents to line up opening and closing braces.)